# How to ensure that node.js script on EC2 instance restarts if it ever crashes?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, daemon

I have a node.js script that is streaming in 1% Twitter data real-time into my S3 bucket. This script is on my EC2 instance and run using forever to ensure that it just runs on the EC2 instance non-stop remotely.

I noticed sometimes that the stream will stop randomly; this might be a dumb question but how do I ensure that if the code stops, that it automatically restarts without me having to check?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like Upstart on ubuntu. Some ideas are [here](https://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit)